# drop down box displays user name, on selection gets user number

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a report function were a manager can look up amendments to a user rota which is a mySQL table. This contains 5 columns Unique_ID ( *Auto Increment*), UserID(*13 digit number*), Date effected(*Unix date*), Date added(*Unix date*), Added_by(*13 digit number*).

To select the the correct data i was populating a drop down from another table which contains username and UserID ( a 13 digit number) however i am stuck with how to select the name ( as no one can remember all staff numbers) and it POST the corresponding user id to the next query.

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['php_SELF']?>" method="get">
<?
    $loc = $usersite->UserLocation();
    $username = "Uname";
    $password = "Pword";
    $hostname = "Hname";
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
        or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    $selected = mysql_select_db("DBname",$dbhandle)
        or die("Could not select database");
    $query="SELECT name FROM `login1st` WHERE `Location` = '$loc'";
    $result = mysql_query ($query);
    echo "<select name=category value=''></option>";
    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo'<option value="'.$nt['name'].'">'.$nt['name'].'</option>';
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="buttons2">
</form>
```

this work fine and i have a drop down box with all staff names, is there a way to get the associated userid from the selection to a separate query? E.G

```
    SELECT * FROM  `$loc` WHERE  `User_id` = (query result from drop down)
```

i am using the PHP_SELF as the result, I am hoping, will go into a table below the drop down. i am open to any other ways of doing this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the value-section you can define what to submit. So just change your query to get the UserId as well

```
$query="SELECT UserID, name FROM `login1st` WHERE `Location` = '$loc'";
```

and then just output the id in your selectbox:

```
echo'<option value="'.$nt['UserID'].'">'.$nt['name'].'</option>';
```